# RestKit Paginator Crash: Cannot determine hasNextPage: paginator is not loaded

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

For some reason, I randomly sometimes get this crash.

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Cannot determine hasNextPage: paginator is not loaded.

Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x309a1f4b __exceptionPreprocess + 130
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3b1386af objc_exception_throw + 38
2  CoreFoundation                 0x309a1e25 +[NSException raise:format:]
3  Foundation                     0x31349fe3 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 90
4  Poka                           0x004f0f71 -[RKPaginator hasNextPage] (RKPaginator.m:151)
5  Poka                           0x00289a41 __66-[PokaLocationContentManagerSingleton fetchLatestPlantsWithCount:]_block_invoke (PokaLocationContentManagerSingleton.m:345)
6  Poka                           0x004f2495 __24-[RKPaginator loadPage:]_block_invoke157 (RKPaginator.m:231)
7  Poka                           0x004e9355 __66-[RKObjectRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:]_block_invoke244 (RKObjectRequestOperation.m:477)
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x3b61bd1b _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x3b61bd07 _dispatch_client_callout + 22
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x3b62278d _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 268
11 CoreFoundation                 0x3096c819 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
12 CoreFoundation                 0x3096b0ed __CFRunLoopRun + 1300
13 CoreFoundation                 0x308d5c27 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
14 CoreFoundation                 0x308d5a0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
15 GraphicsServices               0x355c9283 GSEventRunModal + 138
16 UIKit                          0x33179049 UIApplicationMain + 1136
17 Poka                           0x0006df95 main (main.m:17)
18 libdyld.dylib                  0x3b640ab7 start + 2
```

I am loading the Paginator like this:

```
- (void)fetchLatestPlantsWithCount:(NSNumber *)count
{
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

    NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/api/rest/plants/?count=%@&limit=:perPage&offset=:offset", count];

    NSDictionary *parameters = nil;
    if(_dateFilterLastModifiedAppend)
        parameters = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:_dateFilterLastModifiedAppend, @"last_modified_date__gte", nil];

    RKPaginator *paginator = [objectManager paginatorWithPathPattern:requestString parameters:parameters];

    paginator.perPage = API_PER_PAGE_LIMIT;

    [ZAActivityBar showWithStatus:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Downloading latest plants: %@ remaining", @"PokaLocalizable", nil), count]];

    [paginator setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKPaginator *paginator, NSArray *objects, NSUInteger page) {
        if([paginator hasNextPage])
        {
            [ZAActivityBar showWithStatus:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Downloading latest plants: %@ remaining", @"PokaLocalizable", nil), [NSNumber numberWithInt:([count integerValue] - paginator.offset)]]];
            [paginator loadNextPage];
        }
        else
        {
            [self fetchLatestProductionLinesCount];
        }
    } failure:^(RKPaginator *paginator, NSError *error) {
        [self fetchLatestProductionLinesCount];
    }];

    [paginator loadPage:1];
}
```

Finally, I added some code to RestKit in order to load the paginator. I don't think it is the problem though.

```
- (RKPaginator *)paginatorWithPathPattern:(NSString *)pathPattern parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
{
    NSAssert(self.paginationMapping, @"Cannot instantiate a paginator when `paginationMapping` is nil.");
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:pathPattern parameters:parameters];
    RKPaginator *paginator = [[RKPaginator alloc] initWithRequest:request paginationMapping:self.paginationMapping responseDescriptors:self.responseDescriptors];
#ifdef _COREDATADEFINES_H
    paginator.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
    paginator.managedObjectCache = self.managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache;
    paginator.fetchRequestBlocks = self.fetchRequestBlocks;
#endif
    paginator.operationQueue = self.operationQueue;
    Class HTTPOperationClass = [self requestOperationClassForRequest:request fromRegisteredClasses:self.registeredHTTPRequestOperationClasses];
    if (HTTPOperationClass) [paginator setHTTPOperationClass:HTTPOperationClass];
    return paginator;

}
```

The only difference is that I pass some parameters to it.

The thing I don't understand is that I load other objects, **WITH** that same code with the only difference being the type of objects I am downloading. I execute almost that same code right **before** executing this one, and it works perfectly fine. Hence, my question as to I am confused...

Some more information:

It says the object count is 1, that page is 1, but apparently it is not loaded?

Note that I call the paginator multiple times within the same page. I do the paginator for one type of objects... once it is done I do it for another one... and so on.

Comment: Seems quite clear: Cannot determine hasNextPage: paginator is not loaded. What don't you understand (presumably you have a race condition or a logical failure in your usage of the paginator).

Comment: I added some code Wain.

Comment: The code you show in the question is the only time you call `paginatorWithPathPattern:parameters:` ?

Comment: No, I call it multiple times before. So let's say I am done fetching objects A, and it the paginator doesn't have anymore objects to load for A, I call the same code, but for a different object (let's B) and so on... for a couple of objects. (This is when the user logs into my app).

Comment: Add lots of logging. Log each time you create or use a paginator and where at. Where it crashes, add a check on `loaded` and when it fails breakpoint and check the instance against the log to see where it was created and why it isn't loaded. The code looks ok so you will need to debug.

Comment: Okay thanks! It is weird... it is not crashing anymore, but I have a lot more information to load from my servers. As if when there is nothing to load... there is some type of race that creates a crash... Should I just add a while(!paginator.isLoaded)?!

Answer (score 1):

All pull requests that I mentioned before were merged already to master. So just use the newest version.

---

I found an issue and fixed it if you are interested. I posted Pull Request on RestKit github page

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/pull/2156

I would recommend to use my fork on branch `inventorum` where I also cherry picked `malloc error` fix:

https://github.com/bimusiek/RestKit/commits/inventorum

Comment: Wow! Thanks!

I will integrate it into my code. Thanks a lot! What was the exact issue do you know?!

Comment: Yes. Problem was that sometimes in NSOperation callback is called before KVO got notification about isFinished=true. Theoretically this bug comes from Apple, because they call it on different queues and in race condition callback is delivered before KVO isFinished. (However apple docs says callback is always called after isFinished was changed to true)